# Error connecting to ENS using a web3 instance

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I've written the following code to retrieve wallet names from the Ethereum name service. This was working a month or two ago, but now there is an error with the ens object: **"AttributeError: type object 'ENS' has no attribute 'fromWeb3'"**.

```
from ens import ENS 
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/...'))
print(web3.isConnected())
ns = ENS.fromWeb3(web3)
wallet_name = ns.name('0x123...')
print(wallet_name)
```

web3.isConnected() prints True. The set up is consistent with that on the docs (https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ens_overview.html). Thanks for any help.

****EDIT SOLUTION FOUND ****

I wasn't running my code in a virtual environment, so the ENS connection wasn't working. Follow the 'troubleshooting' instructions here to set up a clean virtual environment and the above code will work.

(https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Based on the current code in github, this should work.  Is it POSSIBLE you created your own file called `ens.py`?  You might do `import ens` / `print(ens.__file__)` and make sure it's the one you think it is.'

Comment: Thanks Tim. Found a solution in the end will edit the post